# Auto-generate class and member from json file in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, auto-generate

I have a simple json file like below. This is fixed in the project.

```
{
    "en": "English",
    "es": "Español",
    "fr": "Français"
}
```

My question is, is it possible to do a auto-generate work to create a class with members which return the value of each key? The result of the auto-generate can be similar to below example. So every time I add new key and value to the json file, this class will generate or update that new item into it.

```
class JsonHelper {
    static String get en => json['en'];

    static String get es => json['es'];

    static String get fr => json['fr'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this site for Auto-generate class in Flutter:

https://app.quicktype.io/?share=pxoAci2ZiiPtLyjXaYhD

another way is using Auto-generator package of npm

**New Edit:** I just found this site: https://jsontodart.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure you can use Auto-generate class in Flutter on this website: [Instantly parse Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acqrq.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acqrq.png)

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final autoGenerate = autoGenerateFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

AutoGenerate autoGenerateFromJson(String str) => AutoGenerate.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String autoGenerateToJson(AutoGenerate data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class AutoGenerate {
    AutoGenerate({
        this.en,
        this.es,
        this.fr,
    });

    String en;
    String es;
    String fr;

    factory AutoGenerate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AutoGenerate(
        en: json["en"],
        es: json["es"],
        fr: json["fr"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "en": en,
        "es": es,
        "fr": fr,
    };
}
```

you can then simply use `final objectFromClass = autoGenerateFromJson(jsonString)`